# Why does my callback function always return to error instead of response in everycase

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm learning node and I'm stuck resolving why callback is always returned to error

Here's my code

```
todo.createTask(req,(err,resp)=>{
if(err){
    res.status(400).send(err);
}else{
    res.status(200).send(resp);
}
});
```

---

```
var createTask(req,callBack) =>{
    var model = new models({
    .
    .
    .
    .
    });

    model.save().then((doc)=>{
        callBack(doc);
    }).catch((err)={
        callBack(err);
    })
}
```

I'm receiving successful msg from mongo with 400 status code that I used for error.

Please help me find what is that I'm doing wrong. My intent here is to respond with statuscode 200 when its a success case and status code 400 in case of error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to update your code like this to signal that error does not exist:

```
var createTask(req,callBack) =>{
    var model = new models({
    .
    .
    .
    .
    });

    model.save().then((doc)=>{
        callBack(null,doc); // here we are returning null as the error, so you say that everything was fine
    }).catch(callback) // since catch expects a callback we can just put the callback here
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there any better way of doing this i.e using something other than callBack

Comment: That depends on the libraries you use. Your options for async code are callbacks, promises and generators. There is nothing wrong with mixing callbacks and promises as long as you don't go mad with them. Just try to use promises when possible and fallback to callbacks when not

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases where your callback is called:

```
callBack(doc);
callBack(err);
```

… in each of them, you pass **one** parameter. That is assigned to the **first** argument.

```
(err,resp)=>{
```

So in each case you assign *something* that is a true value to `err` and *nothing* to `resp`.

Your `if(err){` then takes the true value from the first argument and behaves as you told it to.

If you want to avoid that, you need to pass a false value to `err` and the value you care about to `resp`.

Comment: I dint get this part "If you want to avoid that, you need to pass a false value to err and the value you care about to resp"

Comment: callBack(null, doc);